# The desperate wanderer

Tags: riddle, knowledge

After the bride was won,

Thought it was time to return home.

Sadly the fate was not so kind,

I should not have made him blind.

Now i wander losing my faith,

Keeping in my mind the hope with.

Who am i?

Comment: My first attempt of a riddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> Odysseus

After the bride was won,

> Helen, “won” back to Menelaus during the Battle of Troy

Thought it was time to return home.

> Odysseus, who was there, returned home

Sadly the fate was not so kind,

> The fates didn’t have a simple journey home for him, as detailed in the Odyssey

I should not have made him blind.

> He blinded the cyclops Polyphemus, which led to Poseidon, Polyphemus’ father, coming for revenge

Now i wander losing my faith,

> His journey was long and winding and took many years

Keeping in my mind the hope with.

> The hope of returning home to his wife.

Comment: Don't you mean rot13 juvpu yrq gb Cbfrvqba, uvf sngure,pbzvat sbe eriratr?